# Passing token in KOHA using REST API php

Tags: php, rest, curl

Been trying to pass generated tokens in the header using REST in php in Koha, this is what I have been getting;

```
{"error":"Authentication failure."}
```

Wanted to GET patrons data from koha using the following code;

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
      CURLOPT_URL => "mykohadomain:8000/api/v1/oauth/token",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=clientID&client_secret=clientSecret",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
    ]);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    
    $token = $response->access_token;
    
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    $curl2 = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl2, [
      CURLOPT_URL => "mykohadomain:8000/api/v1/patrons",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$token,
        "Content-Type: application/json"
      ],
    ]);

    $response2 = curl_exec($curl2);
    $err2 = curl_error($curl2);

    curl_close($curl2);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response2);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

The tokens gets printed out correctly, but while passing the token on the second call to GET patrons, I get authorization failure.
Anybody with an idea of how to solve this.

Comment: Had you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

first ensure system preference REST API Option enable
then

php code

```
    $url = "http://YOUR_URL/api/v1/patrons";
    $username = "YOUR_STAFF_ADMIN_YOUR_NAME";
    $password = "STAFF_ADMIN_PASSWORD";
    $data = ["surname"=>"xyz"];

    $ch = curl_init($url);


    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    $d = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r(json_decode($d));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Old now, but this was basic auth and the op was trying to use oauth.